# how to measure the mean absolute error (MAE ) in recommender system

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am building hybrid recommender system  and then I evaluate the model

I want to make sure does this how we calculate the MAE for evaluation (see image )
where the prediction will result from the training dataset and the actual rating will be from the test set 
[MAE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prWR0.png)

thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is, the answer is in the image?

Comment: yes the answer is in the image please check is it correct or not